# ceph remove spurious data

Tags: lvm, ceph, cephfs

I’d like to remove some “spurious" data:

```
root@XX03:/# ceph df
--- RAW STORAGE ---
CLASS     SIZE    AVAIL    USED  RAW USED  %RAW USED
hdd    1.0 PiB  1.0 PiB  47 GiB    47 GiB          0
TOTAL  1.0 PiB  1.0 PiB  47 GiB    47 GiB          0

--- POOLS ---
POOL  ID  PGS  STORED  OBJECTS     USED  %USED  MAX AVAIL
.mgr   1    1  70 MiB       19  209 MiB      0    327 TiB
.nfs   3   32   572 B        4   36 KiB      0    327 TiB
root@XX03:/#
```

as you can see, there are no data pools.
The 47GiB could be from previous pools/filesystems that I used for testing.

how can I remove this “spurious” data without affecting the OSDs?
I was checking "ceph-volume lvm zap”, but I am not sure it this is the right one.

(I am running ceph version quincy 17.2.7)

Thanks,
Giuliano.

EDITED/added:
Here the output of `ceph osd df`

```
ID   CLASS  WEIGHT   REWEIGHT  SIZE     RAW USE  DATA     OMAP     META     AVAIL    %USE  VAR   PGS  STATUS
110    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  343 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  295 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.98    0      up
111    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  343 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  295 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.98    0      up
112    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  347 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  299 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    1      up
113    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  347 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  299 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    3      up
114    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  347 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  299 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    1      up
115    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  343 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  295 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.98    0      up
116    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  343 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  295 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.98    0      up
117    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  343 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  295 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.98    0      up
118    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  347 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  299 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    1      up
119    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  347 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  299 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    1      up
120    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  427 MiB  120 MiB    1 KiB  307 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.01  1.22    2      up
143    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  347 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  299 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    1      up
 11    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  353 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  305 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    2      up
 12    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  349 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  301 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    0      up
 13    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  349 MiB   48 MiB    4 KiB  301 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    2      up
 14    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  345 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    0      up
 15    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  345 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    1      up
 16    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
 17    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  345 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    0      up
 18    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  353 MiB   48 MiB    5 KiB  305 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    3      up
 19    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  345 MiB   48 MiB    5 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    1      up
 20    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  358 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  310 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.02    0      up
 21    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  349 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  301 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    2      up
132    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    1      up
 33    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  357 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  310 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.02    0      up
 34    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  345 MiB   48 MiB    4 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    2      up
 35    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  340 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  292 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.97    0      up
 36    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  353 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  305 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    2      up
 37    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  342 MiB   48 MiB    4 KiB  294 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.98    1      up
 38    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  353 MiB   48 MiB    4 KiB  305 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    1      up
 39    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
 40    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  349 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  301 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    0      up
 41    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  345 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    0      up
 42    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  345 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    1      up
 43    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  349 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  301 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    0      up
135    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
 66    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  362 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  314 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.03    1      up
 67    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  345 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    1      up
 68    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  357 MiB   48 MiB    5 KiB  309 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.02    1      up
 69    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  344 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  296 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.98    1      up
 70    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  351 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  303 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    0      up
 71    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  351 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  303 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    1      up
 72    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  346 MiB   48 MiB    9 KiB  298 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    2      up
 73    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  353 MiB   48 MiB    4 KiB  305 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    1      up
 74    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  341 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  293 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.98    1      up
 75    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  351 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  303 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    1      up
 76    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  341 MiB   48 MiB    4 KiB  293 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.97    0      up
138    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  351 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
 77    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  345 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    1      up
 78    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
 79    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  356 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  308 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.02    1      up
 80    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  345 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    0      up
 81    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  341 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  293 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.98    0      up
 82    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
 83    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
 84    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  344 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    2      up
 85    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  344 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    0      up
 86    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    2      up
 87    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  341 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  293 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.97    1      up
139    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  351 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
 88    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  349 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  301 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    1      up
 89    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  340 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  292 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.97    1      up
 90    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  340 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  292 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.97    1      up
 91    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  353 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  305 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    1      up
 92    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    1      up
 93    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  344 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    0      up
 94    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  349 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  301 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    1      up
 95    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  344 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  296 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.98    0      up
 96    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
 97    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  345 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    0      up
 98    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  356 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  308 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.02    0      up
140    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    1      up
  0    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  338 MiB   48 MiB      0 B  290 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.97    0      up
  1    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  305 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
  2    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  340 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  292 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.97    0      up
  3    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  338 MiB   48 MiB      0 B  290 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.97    1      up
  4    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  357 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  309 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.02    1      up
  5    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    1      up
  6    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  340 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  293 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.97    0      up
  7    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    1      up
  8    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  353 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  305 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    1      up
  9    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    1      up
 10    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  340 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  292 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.97    2      up
133    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  340 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  292 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.97    0      up
 22    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  340 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  292 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.97    3      up
 23    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  341 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  293 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.98    2      up
 24    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  341 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  293 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.98    0      up
 25    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  349 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  301 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    1      up
 26    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  356 MiB   48 MiB    4 KiB  308 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.02    2      up
 27    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  344 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  296 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.98    0      up
 28    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  340 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  292 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.97    0      up
 29    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  340 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  292 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.97    3      up
 30    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  341 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  294 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.98    0      up
 31    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  345 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    1      up
 32    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  351 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  303 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    0      up
134    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  431 MiB  120 MiB    1 KiB  310 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.01  1.23    1      up
 44    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  345 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    1      up
 45    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  349 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  301 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    0      up
 46    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  439 MiB  120 MiB    1 KiB  318 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.01  1.26    2      up
 47    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  350 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  302 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    3      up
 48    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  346 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  298 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    2      up
 49    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  345 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    1      up
 50    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  353 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  305 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
 51    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  345 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    1      up
 52    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  353 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  305 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
 53    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  349 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  301 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    0      up
 54    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  345 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    0      up
136    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
 55    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  349 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  301 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    0      up
 56    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  349 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  301 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    0      up
 57    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
 58    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  345 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    0      up
 59    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  349 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  301 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    0      up
 60    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  349 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  301 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    1      up
 61    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  344 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    0      up
 62    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  349 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  301 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    1      up
 63    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
 64    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  340 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  293 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.97    0      up
 65    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    1      up
137    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  351 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
 99    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  356 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  308 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.02    0      up
100    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  344 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  296 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.98    0      up
101    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  348 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  300 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    1      up
102    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
103    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  340 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  292 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.97    0      up
104    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    2      up
105    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  344 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  296 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.98    0      up
106    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  344 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  296 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.98    0      up
107    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  348 MiB   48 MiB    4 KiB  300 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    0      up
108    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  348 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  300 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    1      up
109    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  356 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  308 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.02    0      up
141    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  340 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  292 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.97    0      up
121    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  340 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  293 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.97    0      up
122    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  353 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  305 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
123    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  344 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  297 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    0      up
124    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
125    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  346 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  298 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  0.99    0      up
126    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  356 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  308 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.02    1      up
127    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    2      up
128    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    3 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    1      up
129    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  349 MiB   48 MiB    1 KiB  301 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.00    1      up
130    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  353 MiB   48 MiB    4 KiB  305 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    1      up
131    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    0      up
142    hdd  7.27739   1.00000  7.3 TiB  352 MiB   48 MiB    2 KiB  304 MiB  7.3 TiB  0.00  1.01    2      up
                        TOTAL  1.0 PiB   49 GiB  6.9 GiB  330 KiB   42 GiB  1.0 PiB  0.00                   
MIN/MAX VAR: 0.97/1.26  STDDEV: 0
```

Comment: How many OSDs do you have? Most likely that's the rocksdb per OSD. Can you share your `ceph osd df` output?

Comment: @eblock, I have 144 OSDs. I updated the ticket and added the output of ceph osd df

Answer (score 0):

According to your `ceph osd df` output it's the OSD's database which takes some space, too. Here's an example from an empty cluster, there are only 3 OSDs of 15 GB size each, no data in the cluster:

```
$ ceph osd df
ID  CLASS  WEIGHT   REWEIGHT  SIZE    RAW USE  DATA     OMAP  META   AVAIL    %USE   VAR   PGS  STATUS
 0    hdd  0.01500   1.00000  15 GiB  6.0 GiB  5.9 MiB   0 B  1 GiB  9.0 GiB  40.03  1.00    1      up
 1    hdd  0.01500   1.00000  15 GiB  6.0 GiB  5.9 MiB   0 B  1 GiB  9.0 GiB  40.03  1.00    1      up
 2    hdd  0.01500   1.00000  15 GiB  6.0 GiB  5.9 MiB   0 B  1 GiB  9.0 GiB  40.03  1.00    1      up
                       TOTAL  45 GiB   18 GiB   18 MiB   0 B  3 GiB   27 GiB  40.03

$ ceph df
--- RAW STORAGE ---
CLASS  SIZE    AVAIL   USED    RAW USED  %RAW USED
hdd    45 GiB  27 GiB  15 GiB    18 GiB      40.03
TOTAL  45 GiB  27 GiB  15 GiB    18 GiB      40.03

  data:
    pools:   1 pools, 1 pgs
    objects: 0 objects, 0 B
    usage:   18 GiB used, 27 GiB / 45 GiB avail
    pgs:     1 active+clean
```

But the raw usage is still 18 GB although no data is stored. In your case the OSD's have around 300 MB each reserved for the db device. You can check the perf dump output to confirm:

```
$ ceph tell osd.0 perf dump | jq -r '.bluefs.db_total_bytes'
5364506624
```

Or alternatively, enter the OSD daemon with cephadm and then query the values:

```
$ cephadm enter --name osd.0
$ ceph daemon osd.0 perf dump | jq -r '.bluefs.db_total_bytes'
```

In my case it's around 5 GB per OSD, adding the metadata accounts for around 6 GB as you can see in the "RAW USE" column, which adds up to the 18 GB RAW USE total.

Comment: thanks @eblock for the explanation. Yes, my META plus DATA gives RAW USE. However, still it is unclear to me why there is DATA and METADATA in a ceph cluster with no pools neither file systems. If this is spurious data, can I delete it, and how?

Comment: No, you can't delete it, those are necessary allocations for the OSDs databases.